# Is there a utPLSQL way to mock procedures, functions, or tables?

Tags: oracle, plsql, unit-test

In tSQLt, you can isolate dependencies for unit testing using procedures like FakeTable to create a dummy version of whatever your test subject depends on, that contains only data you specify. This is just like using Justmock or Moq in .NET unit testing.

The only thing remotely close to this that I've seen for utPLSQL is copying the dependencies to a temp version in the setup procedure, creating the dummy version manually, and then replacing it with the temp version in the teardown, all using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

Is there a more convenient way to do this, short of just creating a procedure to do this myself?